# Find $f$ such that $f''(x) = 2+ \cos x$, $f(0) = -1$, $f(\pi/2) = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find $f$ such that  $f''(x) = 2+ \cos x$, $f(0) = -1$, $f(\pi/2) = 0$

I integrated it once to get, $2x + \sin x + C$, $C$ being a constant. Then I integrated it a second time to get $x^2 - \cos x + Cx + D$, $D$ being another constant. I then have to plug in the values to determine the value of the two constants.

My problem is, I am plugging them in, but getting answers no where close to the actual solution.

The solution is, $x^2 - \cos x - \frac{1}{2 \pi} x$

Thanks.

Comment: Something tells me $\int \cos x dx = \sin x + C$.  Dwell on it.

Comment: The antiderivative of cos is neither cos nor -cos.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do have 2x + sinx + c. That was a typo, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your first step, you meant sin.  But that is not your confusion.

I suspect when trying to calculate C and D you forgot that $\cos (0) \neq 0$. If you did that, you would start off thinking that $D=-1$ (where actually $D=0$), and the calculation of $C$ becomes messier.

Comment: Thank you! I always make an error on what I think I understand the most.